# How to auto-detect the Google Account user age is over 13 years ( using non-family account)?

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

We want to accept only users age 13 years from all users who are signing up with Google and FB.

How to detect the user age is over 13 years ( using non-family account) from Google Login Api?  Is there age field,  or field that is telling user is a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no way of doing this.  In order to do this a user would have to fill out their birth date in their account which is not required by Google.  If the user did fill out their birth date in google they would then have to set that information to public which most people would not do.

Facebook to my knowledge also does not require a user fill out a birth date even if they did i am again not sure that this information would be available to you.